# Windows Task Scheduler does not run a node app with a parameter

Tags: node.js, scheduled-tasks

NODE_ENV=local node app.js

This is the line I'm trying to run that I would run in say Git Bash. I put node as the startup Program/script and NODE_ENV=local app.js as the arguments. It is starting in the folder that contains app.js. It starts and closes immediately.

I've reversed the arguments like so, app.js NODE_ENV=local and that starts the program but it doesn't recognize the variable. Unfortunately, command prompt, powershell and others have similar results. What's the best way to pass in a variable to node or is there some other alternative to task scheduler I should consider? Also, would putting the node startup line in some kind of script be an option?

Comment: Hi there - best to share your code as well as the terminal output. btw, you can't reverse it: `NODE_ENV=local` sets an environment variable for the node environment. This is a common pattern to switch between running your script in "production" and "development" or "local" mode. This is now available in your NodeJs script as `process.env.NODE_ENV`. PS: you may need to add `set` in windows

Answer (score 1):

So this isn't a perfect solution, but I was able to find a workaround using .bat files. I wasn't able to get Task Scheduler to call node and give it both an environment variable and a file to open. It can call a .bat file just fine and here's how mine looks:

cd D:\users\desktop... etc etc

SET NODE_ENV=debug

call node program.js

pause

Comment: You can also do pause<nul to close the cmd as well, otherwise it just stays open